# Cant read value from field jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-mobile

my html code

```
<?php 
  while($results = $user_class->fetch_array($sql)){
?>
  <input type="text" name="price[]" class="price" id="price" 
    size="5px" readonly value="<?php echo $results['price_v'] ?>">
  <select onChange="update(); return false;" name="qty[]" class="quant">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <?php 
      $limit = $results['limiter'];
      for($i=1;$i <= $limit;$i++ ){ 
    ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $i?>"><?php echo $i?></option>
    <?php } ?>
  </select>
```

this is my jquery code

```
$("#example_form tr.raww").each(function(i,o){ 
  if($(o).find(".quant").val()>0) { 
    total += $(o).find(".quant").val() * $(o).find(".price").val(); 
  } 
});
```

if i attach

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
```

**My jQuery can't read the value from the field.

And if i remove that jquery mobile can read value from field.**

http://jsfiddle.net/QJxYv/3/

Is there anything wrong with my jQuery code?

Comment: what's this `$(o)` and where does that comes from.?

Comment: replace the $(o) to $(this)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Look at the code. `o` is from the `.each()` function. It is equal to the element of the current iteration, and thus `$(o)` is equivalent to `$(this)`.

Comment: yes $(o) is $(this) thx for the answer but that not the question bro :D

Comment: Do you see any javascript errors and is it possible to post a jsfiddle of your resulting html (without php code)?

Comment: @afroze i use inspect element in google chroome and no eror found in this code

this is my code in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QJxYv/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will work as long as there is only one element with class quant and one element with class price in each row of class raww.

Comment: there are two issues with your fiddle: your javascript in in an onLoad handler, which hides the update() function, and it is using rupiah which is undefined. Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/robbyn/QJxYv/5/

Comment: ok i set rupiah function. so if i attach jquery mobile  the code is not work see this http://jsfiddle.net/QJxYv/7/ . and this without jquery mobile http://jsfiddle.net/QJxYv/8/ . iwant to use jquery mobile so what i must going to do sir?

Comment: You must add the css as an external resource (before the js)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
     if ($(this).find("select.quant").val() > 0) {
```

and

```
sub_total += $(this).find("select.quant").val() * $(this).find(".price").val();
```

Updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/QJxYv/4/

Comment: Did you change both lines? Also see my fiddle, you can see the log message "loop" in the console using the fiddle given above. Notice that I put the log message (console.log("loop");) in the loop where you check the value of the select element.

Comment: I did test it with jquery mobile in my fiddle. The problem is that when you add jquery mobile to your code it introduces a span element with class="quant" (placed just before your select element), that is why you cannot access the select element immediately. Your selector selects two elements. Therefore you have to use a specific selector. See my fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/QJxYv/4/) that has jquery mobile included as an external reference and its working.

Comment: THANKS BRO ITS WORKING NOW :D, i dont look at console.log("loop"); so the point is i must add 'console.log("loop");' ?